# pass variable from component to view input tag field using props in vue3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I want to pass a varialbe from `AllProductsChoose.vue` compoennet to view in vue3. It can pass one of my variable successfully `choose_product`, but it cannot pass `tmp_sell` to view, and after I pass tmp_sell to view, I want to allocate to input tag field automatic. Here is my comp[onent below:

```
    <template>
     <tr class="choose_product" v-for="p, i in all_products" @click.prevent="choosenOneProduct($event,p, i);" @change="emitEventChanged">
<!--so it will cumulative the p_sell I choose-->
<td> {{ p.p_sell }} </td> 
                <td> <div><button class="btn btn-info" @click.prevent="choosenOneProduct($event,p, i);" > [+] </button> </div> </td>
    </tr>
    </template>
    ...
    export default{
      name: 'all-products-choose',
      props:['choosen_products', 'tmp_sell'],
      setup() {},
      data(){
          return{
          choosen_products: [], //this is example, it works fine
          tmp_sell: 0, //this will changed based on each choosenOneProduct called.
      }
      ...
    choosenOneProduct(ev, p, i){ //while function works fine, it return the value I want
          var choose_product_ref =  firebase.firestore().collection("all_products").where("p_fullname", "==", p.p_fullname);
          choose_product_ref.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
              snapshot.docs.forEach(d => {
                  var product = d.data();
                  var tmp_one_sell = parseFloat(d.data().p_sell);   
                  this.tmp_sell = this.tmp_sell + tmp_one_sell; // it works fine, this is what I want to change
                  this.choosen_products.push(product);
                  this.$root.$emit('choosenOneProduct', this.choosen_products); //it works
                  this.$root.$emit("choosenOneProduct", this.tmp_sell); / it does not work
                
              })
            })
        },
    ...
```

What's the problem with this props? `choosen_products` works fine but not `tmp_sell`, the view is here:

```
    <all-products-choose 
    v-on:choosen_products="getChoosenProducts($event); "  
    v-on:tmp_sell="getTmpSell($event)">
    </all-products-choose>

        <!--the main is this, how to push tmp from component to here?-->
        <input type="number" ref="q_subtotal" placeholder="Subtotal" id="q_subtotal"   />
        
<!--I just want to pass from component to here, so I put like this.-->

         props: ['choosen_products', 'tmp_sell'],

        choosen_products: [],
                    tmp_sell: 0,

         getTmpSell(tmp_sell){ //call when new page ONLY
                    this.tmp_sell = tmp_sell;
                    
                    //document.getElementById('q_subtotal').value = this.tmp_sell;
                },
```

Any help would appricate, I am missing to pass the variable `tmp_sell` to view.

Comment: Consider formatting code with https://prettier.io/playground/ before posting, to increase its readability. I'd also recommend installing `eslint` + `prettier` locally, in your project, as readability impacts efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

#### You have accidentally used the wrong event name, when emitting this.tmp_sell

Change this line:

```
              this.$root.$emit("choosenOneProduct", this.tmp_sell);
```

to this:

```
              this.$root.$emit("temp_sell", this.tmp_sell);
```

You have already defined two events:

```
 <all-products-choose 
    v-on:choosen_products="getChoosenProducts($event); "  
    v-on:tmp_sell="getTmpSell($event)">
    </all-products-choose>
```

Comment: should I create a separate event or function call `temp_sell`?

Comment: You have already got two different event handlers. We will use the second one, which you already reference as `v-on:temp_sell`. You just need to make sure to emit `"temp_sell"` not  `"choosenOneProduct"`.

Comment: What about *"accidentally"* using the same key in `props` and `data`?